# Impossible to cast string object to class object

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am remaking an old program of mine in Visual Studio and in this program I have a list of objects that can be added and removed from a **List**. I'm using the **.WPF framework** so when I want to remove one of these objects, I display in a new window each one object's identifying string (I hope to be more clear once I add the code reference).

The problem is that when I try to remove one of these object from my list, **I have to cast the selected item from my listView, into a class object** (because my list is made of these class objects). When I do the casting it says that it *cannot cast objects of type 'String' into 'myClass'*

I'll leave here the *window.cs* part where it does the listView selection changed

```
private void myObjectsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     myClass ObjectSelected = (myClass)ObjectList.SelectedItem;
     MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
     mainWindow.removeFromList(ObjectSelected);
}
```

And, if it may be of any use, the *window.xaml* ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="bookList"
                  Margin="10"
                  SelectionChanged="bookList_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: Somewhere you called `ToString()` on your objects before putting them into the `ListView`, instead of adding the real objects and letting WPF call `ToString()` automatically.  Remove that extra `ToString()` call.

Comment: I'm guessing that the "old" program bound a list of objects to the list, and the "new" program binds a list of strings instead. There is not a way to generically cast a string to any type of object.

Comment: Also note that normally the XAML for the `ListView` would set `ItemsSource`, it seems you are adding data to the ListView from code instead of using XAML as WPF is designed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. If I understand correctly, `e` will have the selected item's string id. Then you do `ObjectSelected.Remove(a => a.Id == e.Id);`